# Compatible version of Android JobScheduler - alternative

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there a library or at least some open source example that provides functionality of new Android-L JobScheduler API. It is not to hard to implement my own version (with very limited functionality) but on the other hand it is not trivial either.

So to sum it up is there anything that at least can provide subset of functions of new JobScheduler API ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A backport of Android Lollipop's JobScheduler to api 10+
https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat

Comment: @GordonFreeman, did you give it a try? Stable? How close to the original L JobScheduler?

Comment: Note that unless you are in a rare situation where it isn't possible to use, GcmNetworkManager is the official backwards compatibility API.  Anything else you use (that comes as a library you include in your app) is going be a far inferior solution -- you can't write an equivalent to JobScheduler without a process running (almost) all the time, and you want that process to be in Google Play services and not your own app running a lot and wasting the user's RAM.

Comment: @hackbod so that is why Google Services drain 50-90% of battery on all my devices ;) I still prefer AlarmManager because it works even if the services not available on device.

Answer (score 9):

Just use [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager). It provides APIs to schedule tasks. It is available on pre API level 21 devices. On API level 21+ devices it uses Job Scheduler internally.

Comment: To save other people some time: GCM Network Manager seems to require Android version 2.3 or higher. (If anybody knows differently, please let me know.)

Answer (score 7):

You can do some of it yourself, but unfortunately an app cannot itself achieve comparable functionality to a lot of the job scheduler API.  The problem is that monitoring several of the execution criteria that the job scheduler provides (notably charging state, device idleness, and connectivity) would require that your app be running constantly just to receive the broadcasts about those states -- and the performance cost of running constantly will outweigh the other benefits even if your app is the only one doing it.  If every app is trying to run continuously to do the same kind of monitoring, the user's experience is going to be terrible.

The closest you can come in a reasonable way by yourself is to run a service "occasionally" to check the constraints you're interested in, and back off and retry later if they don't hold at the time you check.  You need to be careful about how you're scheduling things, too -- in particular, if you're going to be using the network you need to be *extremely* careful that you are not accidentally causing lots of devices to hit the network at the same time.  Cell carriers get very unhappy if they see simultaneous traffic from your app from every device on their network.  Also, remember to avoid exact alarms if at all possible, so that the OS has leeway to batch your app's work together with others'.

Device-idle / user activity is hard for your app to track by itself, unfortunately, but connectivity and charge state are readily available.

A final tool at your disposal is the Sync Manager, which requires more infrastructure to use but does offer some reasonably powerful scheduling facilities, especially around connectivity requirements.

Comment: I'm aware that JobScheduler that will be launched with Android L has many advantages since it will run on OS level and it will be more efficient than any other solution that I will come up with. The thing is that I want to use new API to make my app more efficient on new platform but also I need same behavior on older devices, aldo it will not be as good as JobService it self. Some sort of compatibily library, if there is no such solution I will not switch to JobScheduler in near future.

Comment: As @nouman-hanif mentioned below, the GCM Network Manager facilities in the Google Play Services suite provides JobScheduler-like semantics on historical versions of Android, and uses the JobScheduler directly on recent versions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the Sync Manager"? Do you have a link? A web search returns lots of different hits for Sync Manager.

Comment: "The Sync Manager" is the system entity responsible for running your app's sync adapters and so on.  I see that it isn't really called that in the documentation, though -- sorry about that.  I'd start out with the basic docs on "sync adapter" facilities in Android, and go from there: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Answer (score 2):

As of November 2015, this library https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat mentions that it is not maintained actively

> Warning this project is not maintained!

Here is a library called Trigger https://github.com/airk000/Trigger which also claims to be a backport of JobScheduler service and has the following features as per its documentation.

1. support multi conditions combination with one job
2. inner conditions: device charging, unmeterred network and idle status
3. support persist job, means that persist-able job can be triggered after device reboot
4. support job's deadline, last chance to be triggered
5. allow your job's action runs in background or main thread, follow your configuration

Comment: To save time: Trigger requires API level 14+.