# Is the Firebase JobDispatcher using the JobScheduler?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

Since my App has to be available for Android versions 4.x I cannot rely solely on the JobScheduler for background activity. The Firebase JobDispatcher is backwards compatible with the versions I need, so I tested it a bit.

My expectation was, that its using Google Play Services when on Android <5 and the JobScheduler API when 5+, as seen on [this slide](https://youtu.be/VC2Hlb22mZM?t=1796) from the *Android battery and memory optimizations* talk on Google I/O 2016.

Jobs which I schedule in my own app using the JobDispatcher and the testapp, which comes with the Firebase JobDispatcher, do work. I don't see any activity when calling `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`. When I am using the JobScheduler directly I can see the jobs there without a problem.

So I guess the slide I linked above is wrong? 
Is it possible to let the JobDispatcher use the JobScheduler when on Android 5+? Maybe with a custom driver?

Comment: Well there is hope that google delivers a JobScheduler driver:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/32#issuecomment-249266296

Answer (score 0):

I get console output on Android 7.1.1 ...not too less:

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler | grep x\ active
```

On past SDK versions `dumpsys jobscheduler` probably just cannot dump what is not there (booting such SDK versions and then issuing the command would show, since when it works).

While since Android 7.0.0 there is a new command for the `jobscheduler`:

```
adb shell cmd jobscheduler help

Job scheduler (jobscheduler) commands:
  help
    Print this help text.
  run [-f | --force] [-u | --user USER_ID] PACKAGE JOB_ID
    Trigger immediate execution of a specific scheduled job.
    Options:
      -f or --force: run the job even if technical constraints such as connectivity are not currently met
      -u or --user: specify which users job is to be run; the default is the primary or system user
```

The job **scheduler** and the job **dispatcher** are two whole different things; the dispatcher already **is** the driver for backwards-compatibility (therefore one can not expect the OS to have the scheduler).

See [JobSchedulerShellCommand.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5d34605/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerShellCommand.java) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412775/549372) might explain it further.

The [android-job](http://evernote.github.io/android-job/) library also does quite the same, in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With 'I don't see any activity in the shell' I meant  for my app. Without a proper JobScheduler Driver the JobDispatcher ist pretty useless right now. I build a rudimentary Scheduler-Driver for it myself but I am dissapointed nonetheless. There is close to no activity on the GitHub project and the promised functionality are [still missing a year later](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/32). In hindsight I should have used the Evernote Android-Job library.