# Firebase Job Dispatcher Execution Window

Tags: android, android-location, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

**Task**: I want to fetch user's location between 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM. 
So, i thought to use Job Scheduler but not able to set it to above time slot.

Please help me to understand firebase job scheduler.

**And please tell me how to set scheduler to above (9:00 AM to 9:00PM) slot.**

**Tried to do something below:**

```
 firebaseJobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
            Job constraintReminderJob = firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(DispatcherService.class)
                .setTag("")
                .setConstraints(Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING)
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(
                   ?,?
                ))
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                .build();

            firebaseJobDispatcher.schedule(constraintReminderJob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you can use plain recurring jobs for this. For sure not with the Firebase scheduler, because, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720015/firebase-jobdispatcher-how-does-it-work-compared-to-previous-apis-jobschedule?rq=1) good reply,

> windowStart is the earliest time (in seconds) the job should be
>   considered eligible to run. Calculated from when the job was scheduled
>   (for new jobs) or last run (for recurring jobs)

So I think the main path to follow is the `AlarmManager` one that schedules a FireBase Job at specified time (9:00AM) with no repetition and one-hour tolerance, something like `executionWindow(0, 60*60)`