# Http request in background with Firebase job dispatcher: asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using Firebase Job Dispatcher and setting it up like described in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/README.md.

The job to be scheduled is a http request. The http request could run while the app is on the foreground (the user is looking at it), or while the app is in the background/not started.

Should the http request (using [the okhttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)) be put in a separate thread / asynchronous or can I just call it directly from the JobService?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JobService` extends `Service` so it runs on the main thread. Therefore, you shouldn't be able to make network calls directly. However, there is `SimpleJobService` where you can make direct calls.

I think using `SimpleJobService` is better than using `AsyncTask` within `JobService` because it already does it in its own way as you can see [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/SimpleJobService.java).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the JobService class itself. I checked the Documentatieonderdelen on JobService which states: "This service executes each incoming job on a Handler running on your application's main thread. This means that you must offload your execution logic to another thread/handler/AsyncTask of your choosing. Not doing so will result in blocking any future callbacks from the JobManager - specifically onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters), which is meant to inform you that the scheduling requirements are no longer being met." So the network call must have its own thread.

Comment: That's right. As for OkHttp, calling the asynchronous `enqueue()` method inside `JobService` should suffice. In `SimpleJobService`, the synchronous `execute()` method can be called directly since `SimpleJobService` does the given job in a separate `AsyncJobTask`.

Comment: +1 for SimpleJobService. I found it in the source code at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/. How did you find this class? In the README.md on their github account, I could not find any API documentation, or even a javadoc. Do you have more information on this?

Comment: I think I first came across in the I/O presentation link given in the readme: https://youtu.be/VC2Hlb22mZM?t=30m23s. Answer to 10th question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412775/876267) was also helpful.