# How to check if a job is scheduled in firebase job dispatcher?

Tags: android, job-scheduling, firebase-job-dispatcher

How to check if a job is scheduled in firebase job dispatcher? The below code is for Job scheduler api -

```
public static boolean isJobServiceOn( Context context, int JOB_ID ) {
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE ) ;

        boolean hasBeenScheduled = false ;

        for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
            if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {
                hasBeenScheduled = true ;
                break ;
            }
        }

        return hasBeenScheduled ;
    }
```

Is there anything likes it in firebase job dispatcher?

Comment: have you got the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a way to check if my JobDispatcher is already scheduled but AFAIK I don't think we have any method to check if a JobDispatcher is already scheduled.

You can checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412775/3041015